# Minimum K values of a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am aware of an implementation to compute the inverse (i.e. tf.nn.top_k computes the K largest values along a given axis), but I can't find a in-built method to find the K *smallest* values.

Aside from taking the inverse or playing around with sets, is it possible to do this using the tensorflow library, or will I have to devise something myself?

Cheers/

Comment: Using `top_k` on the negatives actually seems like a reasonable alternative in the absence of a `bottom_k`. Why do you seem bothered?

Comment: Something like the following should work bottom_k = lambda x: -tf.nn.top_k(-x)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no single function that you can use. There is no problem using [`tf.nn.top_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) for this purpose. Just negate the argument:

`-tf.nn.top_k(-A)` will do the same as `tf.negative(tf.nn.top_k(tf.negative(A)))`