# Return k smallest elements from a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of shape `(16, 512, 4096)` in tensorflow, I want to calculate the `k` smallest elements from a tensor.

Please note that I am able to acquire it in pytorch using following code snippet-

```
#inputs.shape (16L, 512L, 4096L)
dists, inputs_idx = torch.topk(inputs, 64, 2, largest=False, sorted=False)
#dists.shape (16L, 512L, 64L), inputs_idx.shape (16L, 512L, 64L)
```

Any workaround, please?

Comment: There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548227/minimum-k-values-of-a-tensor) thread.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan: Thank you very much. I am looking into it. Can you tell me how to provide  `dim=2` parameter to `tf.nn.top_k` as per the above question?

Comment: You may have to add a small example and what you expect to the question.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan: I was able to solve it by looking at the documentation carefully. Thank you very much. Meanwhile, can you please answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52119162/1175065)?

Answer (score 0):

Since `tf.math.top_k` can be used to get the `k` largest elements, you can negate the values, perform the operation, then negate them again to get the values back:

```py
-tf.math.top_k(
    -x, k
)
```

Pass `sorted=False` to obtain an equivalent formula to the code you sent in the question.