# Different behavior of gather() function as seen in tensorflow and pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I have a tensor of shape `(16, 4096, 3)`. I have another tensor of indices of shape `(16, 32768, 3)`. I am trying to collect the values along `dim=1`. This was initially done in pytorch using `gather` function as shown below-

```
# a.shape (16L, 4096L, 3L)
# idx.shape (16L, 32768L, 3L)
b = a.gather(1, idx)
# b.shape (16L, 32768L, 3L)
```

Please note that the size of output `b` is the same as that of `idx`. However, when I apply `gather` function of tensorflow, I get a completely different output. The output dimension was found mismatching as shown below-

```
b = tf.gather(a, idx, axis=1)
# b.shape (16, 16, 32768, 3, 3)
```

I also tried using `tf.gather_nd` but got in vain. See below-

```
b = tf.gather_nd(a, idx)
# b.shape (16, 32768)
```

Why am I getting different shapes of tensors? I want to get the tensor of the same shape as calculated by pytorch.

**How to achieve the same result as given by pytorch?**

Comment: any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then `tf.gather_nd` is what you are looking for. If not, please be a little more clear.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Can you please have a look once again? The question has been updated!